# Laravel 4 email sending via Madrill SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-4, mandrill

I have some problem with sending email using Mandrill SMTP in Laravel 4. I'm trying to send message with Mail class

```
Mail::send('emails.test', $message, function($email)
    {                       
        $email->to('email@gmail.com', 'User Name')->subject('Welcome message!')->from('emaill2@gmail');
    }
```

Here is my SMTP configuration

```
'host'=>'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
'port'=>587,
'encryption'=>'tls',
'username'=>'emai@gmail.com',
'password'=>'mandrill api key'
```

Also I was trying send email using Gmail SMTP and that works perfect!
Any suggestion?
Thank You!

Comment: Please explain 'some problems'; it's a little bit to vague to come up with a solution....

Comment: actually I don't know what's going wrong because I don't get any error, so I can't explain why it's not working with Mandrill

Comment: @RobGordijn I use Mail::pretend() and get this `[2013-09-11 20:19:33] log.INFO: Pretending to mail message to: email@gmail.com [] []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pretending mail only the email address will be displayed. Have a look at the source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php?source=cc#L309

Comment: Omg the problem was in FROM atribut, it must be my email wich i use during registration in Mandrill.